# show custom toolbar only with certain xls-file

Tags: excel, toolbar, vba

i have a macro (Makro1) that is assigned to a button in a custom toolbar (Custom1) with caption "Schutzstatus". i want the toolbar only to be loaded with this very xls-file.

can someone help me out with the code?

i managed to customize the tooltip:

```
Application.CommandBars("Custom1").Controls(1).TooltipText = "Abfrage des Schutzstatus der Arten im Zwischenspeicher"
```

but i fail in creating the whole thing by vba..

thanks in advance,
kay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need to (re)create the whole toolbar on loading your XLS, but you need to display/hide it during certain navigations

1 create the toolbar

2 attach it to your XLS (view / toolbars / customize .... / attach)

3 create event procedures to show/hide your toolbar; unless you want to have a specific behaviour for different sheets, the following should be enough to care for all navigation:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    ' show toolbar
    Application.CommandBars("CoolBar").Visible = True
    Application.CommandBars("CoolBar").Controls(1).TooltipText = "C'mon squeeze me"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ' drop toolbar
    Application.CommandBars("CoolBar").Delete
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
' see if we have a toolbar (it might have been already deleted by "Workbook_BeforeClose"
' if yes - hide it
Dim Idx As Integer

    For Idx = 1 To Application.CommandBars.Count
        If Application.CommandBars(Idx).Name = "CoolBar" Then
            Application.CommandBars("CoolBar").Visible = False
        End If
    Next Idx
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
' display toolbar
    Application.CommandBars("CoolBar").Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Application.CommandBars("CoolBar").Visible = False
End Sub
```

Place all in the "ThisWorkbook" object - so they fire on all sheets.

4 After saving the toolbar with the XLS and testing, close the XLS - the toolbar will be still present in your application object - and delete the toolbar from there. Don't panic, it's coming back when you re-open your XLS file.

Hope this helps
Tschüss MikeD

Comment: hi and thanks! one thing: when i run this xls from another computer does the command bar still work then with this approach?

Comment: another thing: when i do "Application.CommandBars("CoolBar").Delete" with event Workbook_BeforeClose, isn't the toolbar gone for good?

Comment: *ad 1* yes ... as the command bar is stored with your XLS data file and - upon opening - is coppied to the Excel Application object

Comment: *ad 2* No because you delete it only from the Application object as the first part of the statement suggests; after (re)opening the data file the game starts again. To really remove it "unwiederbringable" you have to delete it from both application and sheet at the sanme time, then save the sheet.

Comment: i did as suggested (created toolbar "CoolBar", assigned macro and saved and closed file) but when i reopen the toolbar is gone, even can't see it in the view menu..

Comment: did you do step 2 (attaching Coolbar to your own workbook) ? anyway, grab an example from www.dauda.at/download/CoolBar.xls

Comment: NOTE: I added one line to the Activate trigger to do a custom tooltip - as you did; it's normally enough to call it from here; and I changed the name of the bar in the Deactivate trigger, it previously showed the name of my REAL toolbar ;-) (because this is coming from a working real life example)

Comment: MikeD - many, many thanks! i wonder why this approach is not propagated elsewhere (when i was searching for how to share custom-toolbars my impression was that most sources rather point at  programatically creating toolbars..) best wishes!

Comment: I know and made the same observation a long time ago ... but I was tired of writing all that code to create toolbars ... especially when you want to do them nicely with icons and stuff you write your fingers off ... so I chose the simple way ... Liebe Grüsse aus Wien

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer was close but didn't work for me. That .Delete does delete the command bar completely as confirmed by Kay in his last comment. You basically had to recreate but bar and button again when the workbook is opened. Below is the improved code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    ' show toolbar
    Dim SortBar As CommandBar
    Dim BarControl As CommandBarControl

    Set SortBar = FindCommandBar("SortBar")

    If SortBar Is Nothing Then
        Set SortBar = Application.CommandBars.Add("SortBar")

        Set BarControl = SortBar.Controls.Add
        BarControl.OnAction = "Your_Macro_Name"
        BarControl.Caption = "Text for your button"
        BarControl.Style = msoButtonCaption
    End If
    SortBar.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ' drop toolbar
    Application.CommandBars("SortBar").Delete
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
' see if we have a toolbar (it might have been already deleted by "Workbook_BeforeClose"
' if yes - hide it
    Dim SortBar As CommandBar
    Set SortBar = FindCommandBar("SortBar")
    If Not SortBar Is Nothing Then
        SortBar.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Function FindCommandBar(Name As String) As CommandBar
Dim Idx As Integer
    For Idx = 1 To Application.CommandBars.Count
        Set FindCommandBar = Application.CommandBars(Idx)
        If FindCommandBar.Name = Name Then
             Exit Function
        End If
    Next Idx
    Set FindCommandBar = Nothing
End Function

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
' display toolbar
    Application.CommandBars("SortBar").Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Application.CommandBars("SortBar").Visible = False
End Sub
```